# Bottle server connection refused after executing few routes

Tags: python, server, bottle

Bottle server was running perfectly until I have to just call different routes and print out different values on different routes. When I have placed a code in which there is few seconds delay. Code stops after executing few routes and mentio9n connection refused. What can be the possible reason of this and what will be solution.

Comment: You will need to show code and error messages for anyone to have any hope of helping you. I'm not familiar with botle but flask can be run in debug mode, perhaps a similar thing is possible in bottle, which may give more clues about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous vs Asynchronous.  Bottle is a WSGI app, and most of the engines that it runs with are synchronous.  Which means anything (even a sleep timer) will delay subsequent connections.  This really becomes apparant during database queries while the system waits for IO.  If this is happening, switching to an async engine (gevent) could be all that's needed.